# How can I fscanf () a specific type?

Tags: c

I have a data file

```
12345678
3.78 <<GPA
3
20.5

87654321
2.65 <<GPA
2
19.25

08651234
3.10 <<GPA
1
18.0

11112222
3.95 <<GPA
4
22.5

22223234
2.45 <<GPA
3
19.3333
```

What should I do in order to `fscanf()` all the GPA values?
I have to use a function to `fscanf()` the values, I cannot just
 `fscanf(infile, "%lf%lf", &unsaved, &save);` 
Please help me, thanks!

Comment: `fscanf(infile, "%*lf%lf%*lf%*lf", &save);`

Comment: Use `fgets` to read lines from the file, and `sscanf` to convert values on the lines you care about.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read only `GPA` with **assignment suppression** of additional parameters in the `fscanf` format string, you will need a format string similar to `fscanf (fp, "%*lf%lf%*s%*lf%*lf*", &save);`. You must make allowance for the sting characters in the blocks of data or you will experience an **input failure** with `fscanf`. An example of isolating `GPA` using `fscanf` in a function would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readgpa (char *filenm)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen (filenm, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "\n  Error, invalid filename '%s'\n\n", filenm);
        exit (1);
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    double save;

    while (fscanf (fp, "%*lf%lf%*s%*lf%*lf*", &save) != -1)
    {
        cnt++;
        printf (" line: %d    GPA: %.2f\n", cnt, save);
    }

    if (fp) fclose (fp);

}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "\n  Error, insufficient input. Usage: %s filename\n\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    readgpa (argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/gpa dat/gpa.dat
 line: 1    GPA: 3.78
 line: 2    GPA: 2.65
 line: 3    GPA: 3.10
 line: 4    GPA: 3.95
 line: 5    GPA: 2.45
```